# Energy bound for a closed curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, integral-inequality

Let $\gamma : S^1 \rightarrow M$ be a smooth map from a circle of length 1 to a closed manifold $M$ with nonpositive curvature. Could we find a constant $C > 0$ depending only on $M$ such that $$\int_{S^1}||\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}||^2 \ge C\int_{S^1}||\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}||^2$$ for arbitrary $\gamma$?

I have constructed counterexamples on the 2-sphere and a noncompact manifold with negative curvature; that's the reason for the assumption on $M$.

Comment: Did you check the case of the Euclidean plane?

Comment: Yes I check the case when $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ or the flat torus $\mathbb{T}^n$, and I find a bound for both cases to be $4\pi^2$. But I use fourier series to find the bound in these cases so it give no insights into the general situation.

Comment: For the above comment I have assumed the length of $S^1$ to be $1$, if the length is $L$, then the bound should be $\frac{4\pi^2}{L^2}$.

Comment: Are you assuming an arclength parametrization? Even with constant speed, homogeneity is wrong to get a universal bound, I wonder.

Comment: I am not assuming arclength parametrization; it's just that the integral is over $S^1$, so the bound could depend on the total length of $S^1$.

Comment: No, I stand by my complaint. If the magnitude of $\dot\gamma$ varies, you get a mess.

Comment: Ah sorry I write it wrong, the integral is over $S^1$ not $\gamma$.

Comment: I derive the bound as follow: let $t \in [0, 1)$ be the coordinate of $S^1$, in the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the inequality is just $$\int_0^1 \Sigma_i (\frac{\partial^3 \gamma^i}{\partial t^3})^2 \ge C \int_0^1 \Sigma_i (\frac{\partial^2 \gamma^i}{\partial t^2})^2$$. Let $u = \frac{\partial^2 \gamma^i}{\partial t^2}$, then we have $ \int_0^1 u = 0$. viewing $u$ as a periodic function (since the curve is closed) and writes it as a fourier series, so $u = \Sigma_n c_n e^{-2\pi in}$. then the RHS of the inequality becomes $\Sigma_n |c_n|^2$, while the RHS becomes $\Sigma_n 4\pi^2 n^2|c_n|^2$.

Comment: So we get the bound $C = 4\pi^2$.